# micronaut not creating table Flyway

Tags: java, sql, flyway, micronaut

I have a problem. I want the person table to be created when micronaut starts up. To do this, I use flyway, connected the dependency like this:

```
    //----Micronaut Data
    implementation("io.micronaut.data:micronaut-data-jdbc")
    implementation("io.micronaut.sql:micronaut-jdbc-hikari")
    implementation("io.micronaut.sql:micronaut-jooq")

    //---FlyWay and Postgresql
    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    implementation("io.micronaut.flyway:micronaut-flyway")
    runtimeOnly("org.flywaydb:flyway-core")
```

Further, in application.yml I wrote the configuration for Flyway. I will send the entire application yml file:

```
micronaut:
  application:
    name: demo7
  server:
    port: 9000
datasources:
  default:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    db-type: postgres
    dialect: POSTGRES
    username: postgres
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/disa
    password: 1234

netty:
  default:
    allocator:
      max-order: 3
flyway:
  datasources:
    enabled: true
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/disa
    username: postgres
    password: 1234
```

When the application starts, no errors are thrown, but the table is not created either. My db.migration path looks like this:
[image]

Name of my SQL script: **V1_1__create_all_tables.sql**
Help me please.
My sql script:

```
CREATE TABLE person(
                       id   bigint primary key not null,
                       name varchar(255)       not null,
                       age  int                not null
)
```

Comment: Why do you declare `runtimeOnly("org.flywaydb:flyway-core")`? IMO, thats not necessary since it is a transitive dependency of `io.micronaut.flyway:micronaut-flyway`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you add the datasource name `default` to your Flyway configuration.

```yaml
flyway:
  datasources:
    default:
      enabled: true
```

And you don't need to copy the credentials and the connection string.